# IServiceGatewayFactory IOC Registrations

Tags: servicestack

Using ServiceStack and a different IOC container, LightInject, than the default, what do I need to register so that the dependant classes (ServiceStackController, Service, etc) get the correct Gateway.

Example:

```
LightContainer.Register<ServiceStack.Web.IServiceGatewayFactory>(x => new ApiServiceGatewayFactory(), new PerRequestLifeTime());
LightContainer.EnableMvc();
//later
 public class HomeController : ServiceStackController
   {
    public HomeController()
    {
        // is null
        Gateway.Send<SpeakerRequest>(new SpeakerRequestReq() { Id= new Guid("deda0678-cea5-4c23-b6b0-af2455ed6c66") });

    }
```

The `Gateway` property on the controller is still null so I'm not sure what else I need to register to get this wired up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ServiceGateway should be registered in ServiceStack's `AppHost.Configure()` but then should naturally be resolved as long as the [Container Adapter is registered with the external IOC](http://docs.servicestack.net/ioc#use-another-ioc-container).

If it's not resolving you can try resolving the factory directly from LightContainer by overriding:

```
public virtual IServiceGateway GetServiceGateway(IRequest req)
{
    var factory = LightContainer.GetInstance<IServiceGatewayFactory>();
    return factory != null ? factory.GetServiceGateway(req) 
        : Container.TryResolve<IServiceGateway>()
        ?? new InProcessServiceGateway(req);
}
```

Comment: I ended up getting this to work, however the docs state `Capturing the current IRequest makes the Gateway factory instance non-suitable to use as a singleton, so we’ll need to register it with a ReuseScope.None scope so a new instance is resolved each time:`

Comment: @lucuma Right the docs were right and have updated my answer.